# SQL Server 2012 Express Service Pack 2 - installation error 0x84B40001

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 Express Service Pack 2 through command line:

```
SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe /ACTION=Install /HIDECONSOLE  /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="SOMEPWD" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service"
```

However I get this error message:

> The syntax of argument "/HIDECONSOLE" is incorrect;Either the
>   delimiter '=' is missing or there is one or more space characters
>   before the '='"  Error 0x84B40001

I removed the entire `/HIDECONSOLE` argument in my command, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

@Nissanna, As you said, you are getting the error during cmd installation of sql server express 2012.

> The syntax of argument "/HIDECONSOLE" is incorrect;Either the
>   delimiter '=' is missing or there is one or more space characters
>   before the '='" Error 0x84B40001

when you are running this syntax:

> SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe /ACTION=Install /HIDECONSOLE  /FEATURES=SQL
>   /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="SOMEPWD"
>   /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
>   /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT
>   AUTHORITY\Network Service"

I would like to say that definitely you are doing some arguments mistake or permission. As MSDN BOL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.110).aspx the simple syntax of installation would be as mention below format:

> Setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER
>   /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""
>   /SQLSVCPASSWORD=""
>   /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT
>   AUTHORITY\Network Service" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS

**NB:** `For local installations, you must run Setup as an administrator.`

AS local installations, you must run Setup as an administrator. If you install SQL Server from a remote share, you must use a domain account that has read and execute permissions on the remote share. For failover cluster installations, you must be a local administrator with permissions to login as a service, and to act as part of the operating system on all failover cluster nodes.

As your refence https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/87bb5999-1126-4809-a353-0f5b06c9f81d/sql-express-2008-command-line-options and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The above error is caused because there are two or more space characters before parameters. 
Remove the extra spaces after '/HIDECONSOLE'

Also,check and remove if any other extra spaces remaining.

Hope it works.